# programmatically clear image cache in android

Tags: android, caching

I want to clear the cache in my android application and to achieve this I used the two methods given below but the cache doesn't get cleared after calling deleteCache(getApplicationContext()). This question is asked in SO multiple times but none of the answers seems to help me. Below are the methods I used. Thanks for your help.

```
public static void deleteCache(Context context) {

    try {

        File dir = context.getCacheDir();

        if (dir != null && dir.isDirectory()) {

            deleteDir(dir);
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {}
}

public static boolean deleteDir(File dir) {

    if (dir != null && dir.isDirectory()) {

        String[] children = dir.list();

        for (int i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {

            boolean success = deleteDir(new File(dir, children[i]));

            if (!success) {

                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    return dir.delete();
}
```

Comment: are the errors shown in logcat? or it return false?

Comment: Thanks Randyka, no errors are shown in logcat and it returns true.

Answer (score 0):

As you didn't mention any specific logs or problems that you are facing, ["not working" is not a specific problem :) ]

Try this -

```
private void deleteRecursive(File fileOrDirectory) {

        if (fileOrDirectory.isDirectory())
            for (File child : fileOrDirectory.listFiles())
                deleteRecursive(child);

        fileOrDirectory.delete();

    }
// from the point you want to clear-

deleteRecursive(context.getCacheDir());
```

Comment: Hi Amit, when I say it doesn't work I mean the cache is not cleared and I don't encounter any error.  Thanks a lot but your solution didn't help either. BTW, I'm putting my images on DiskLruCache if this info is important.

Comment: are you using any specific image loading library? @Fissehaye, could you share how did you use DIskLruCache to store images? on a general note, to clear DiskLruCache calling "delete()" is not enough, we need to call "deleteContents()"

Comment: Make sure you are using context.getCacheDir() in your DiskLruCache. Otherwise, clear the directory which you are setting in your DiskLruCache path. I believe you need to post the image caching code of yours to detect specific problem further.